# SqlBulkCopy class in C# is changing a numeric value

Tags: c#, console, sqlbulkcopy

I am using `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`-method to insert bulk data to database table. When I am passing a datatable as the parameter of the method `WriteToServer`, some numeric values `(numeric(17,6))` is getting subtracted by `.000001` while it is inserted in database table. But not all values are getting changed, it is happening randomly, couldn't identify the pattern. e.g.- `10068.121` is being changed to `10068.120999`

Now when I am passing a datareader as the parameter of the method WriteToServer, it is working fine, the numeric values remain unchanged.

Any idea why it is happening for datatable and not for datareader?
My application is a C# console application.

Here is my code… if I pass the datatable (_dt) to _sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer method, then I have the issue. But when I convert the datatable (_dt) to DataTableReader (_Reader), it is working fine.

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
_odbCDA.Fill(_dt);
DataTableReader _Reader = new DataTableReader(_dt);

using (SqlBulkCopy _sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_sqlConnectionString)) 
{
     _sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 3600;
     _sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = _tableName;
     _sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(_Reader); //This works
     //_sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt); //This is having the issue
     _sqlBulkCopy.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain without an example reproduction, but if I had to guess when you're using `DataReader` you're copying data between two tables that have the same definition/precision for the numeric type, but when using `DataTable` the column does not have matching precision.  Presumably this is because the `DataReader` isn't mapping things into .NET types, but the `DataTable` is.

I *think* (but have not tested) .NET types map about like so (at least in SQL Server):

- C# `float` -> SQL `real`
- C# `double` -> SQL `float`
- C# `decimal` -> SQL `money` or `numeric`

SQL let's you specify precision in ways C# doesn't, so if you're working with C# built-in types there's a solid chance you're performing conversions to and from `numeric(17,6)` which could lose precision.

If my guess is correct, the `DataType` on the affected `DataColumn` in the `DataTable` will be something like `System.Double`, `System.Single`, or `System.Decimal`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin....I am sorry I didn't mention that...I converted the same datatable to datareader, so the precision, scale everything is same. And in my debug I found correct value is showing in the datatable (which is passing as the parameter in the method SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer)....So, The issue is only in the SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer method, which changes the value and inserts in database table.

Comment: Could you add your conversion code, and the various types involved to the question?  I don't quite follow how you could express `numeric(17,6)` in C#, and the code might help.

Comment: Kevin, I have added the code in my issue description. And I meant Numeric(17,6) is corresponding database field type.

Comment: @DebasisD Looking at [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,1061), it seems like SqlBulkCopy will treat readers and tables rather differently in some cases.  My gut is still there's a conversion going on with `DataTable`, [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) suggest so.  What are the values of `_dt.Columns[<index of troublesome column>].DataType`  and `_Reader.GetFieldType(<index of troublesome column>)` ?

Comment: Kevin, I have checked the field type, both are Double. column name is 'shares'. The strange case is, this issue is not happening for all values under the _dt.column, out of 2 million records, I found only 312, Rest is unchanged.        dt.Columns[<index of troublesome column>].DataType = "Double"   and   _Reader.GetFieldType(<index of troublesome column>) = "Double".

Comment: I also experienced this but in my case the dataTable value was 0.8 but in MS SQL using SqlBulkCopy it was 0.9.  Using the dataReader fixed the issue.